# Get URL from remote URL in webview and open it in safari

Tags: html, webview, titanium

I have a webview in my application and I also have a website online. I have loaded my website in my webview and when I press a link in my website I want to open that link in Safari and not in my webview, here´s what I have done.

I have my webview:

```
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    url: 'http://www.TEST.com', // dummy url now
    top: 42,
    left: 0,
    width: 310,
    height: 275
});
```

My HTML file (which I will put online so I will only access it trough my www address):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="img.css">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
     <body onload="Ti.API.info('body loaded!');">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <ul class="slide" id="slideOne">
          <li><img src="images/1.jpg" onClick="Ti.App.fireEvent('openlink',{url:'http://www.google.com'})"/></li>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And to access the HTML code I have the following code::

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('openlink', function(e) {
   alert('Ti.App);
   Ti.Platform.openURL(e.url);
});
```

But nothing happens when I press the image, anyone has a clue why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do this on a remote web site.

[From this guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Communication_Between_WebViews_and_Titanium-section-29004919_CommunicationBetweenWebViewsandTitanium-Remotewebcontent), in the *Remote web content* section:

> You cannot use any Titanium statements within HTML content loaded from a remote host.

Comment: As you said Josiah this can only be done from a local html file.

Answer (score 3):

Aaron Saunders was real close. Not bad for just typing it up on the fly! I've modified it to use beforeload and instead of using a string check, I use a property from the [beforeload event](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView-event-beforeload) (e).

```
  $.webView.addEventListener('beforeload', function(e) {
    if (e.navigationType == Titanium.UI.iOS.WEBVIEW_NAVIGATIONTYPE_LINK_CLICKED) {

       // stop the event
       e.bubble = false;

       // stop the url from loading
       $.webView.stopLoading();

       // open in safari
      Ti.Platform.openURL(e.url);
  }});
```

Comment: Confirmed this works on iOS with SDK version 6.0.1.GA

Answer (score 1):

you can try to intercept the loading of the new url in your application and redirect to a new safari instance.

this code is not tested... i just typed it up here to give you a general idea

```
// if i have http then assume external url
$.webView.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    if (e.url.indexOf("http") !== -1) {

         // stop the event
         e.bubble = false;

         // stop the url from loading
         $.webView.stopLoading();

         // open in safari
        Ti.Platform.openURL(e.url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don´t think it´s possible to do this in a remote URL unfortunately.

Comment: i suggest you try it... all loads in the webview fire the event

Comment: Why don't you use event `beforeload`?

Answer (score 1):

Yikes, these answers are so wrong.

The Titanium.UI.Webview has a specific property for intercepting links: `onlink`.

This is not implemented as an event because it is a callback and needs to return a boolean to tell the Webview whether or not to load the URL of the link.

Oddly, setting the `onlink` callback right away makes the URL immediately load in Safari, so I did it this way:

```
$.webview.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    $.webview.onlink = function(e) {
        Ti.Platform.openURL(e.url);
        return false;
    };
});
```

You can of course check the `e.url` string and decide whether to open it internally or externally.

Comment: When loading HTML into the Webview, this seems the only solution that does work.